# List all files in Windows Phone 8 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

How can we use JavaScript to list all picture files or music files on a Windows Phone 8 device?

I need to search the default storage as well as SD card storage and list all files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly do that. JavaScript isn't a natively supported language on Windows Phone currently. You'd need to provide a bridge to that functionality in a native host. You'd need to write in C# for example.

Then, you'd need to make sure the application has the correct privileges.

For the SD card, you'd need to do something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612988/windows-phone-8-file-list-of-sd-card-files) answer.

The rest are documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary).